# Probability and confidence intervals

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm rather new to statistics so please bear with me.  Assume that someone claims to you that the probability of A is given by some constant, let's call it c, Indeed, P(A)= c.  Now, let's says that i wish to test his claim and I want to be 99.9 percent confident that he is telling the truth.
Is there a way to design an experiment to test his claim?

Comment: Except in extraordinary circumstances you cannot be confident at all that the probability is $c$ and not $c + 0.00000000001$. But if all you want to know is whether the probability is _at least_ $c$ ($P(A) \geq c$), or it is _no more than_ $c$ ($P(A) \leq c$), or _approximately_ $c$ ($c - \delta \leq P(A) \leq c + \delta$ for some reasonable $\delta$), and you can come up with a suitable repeatable empirical test to see how often $A$ is true, then typically yes, it is possible to design such an experiment.

Comment: It might help if you could be more specific about what the event $A$ is in your particular case, what $c$ is, and what kind of truth you are concerned about. For example, is the claim a "lie" if the claim was $P(A)=0.8$ and it turns out that actually $P(A) \approx 0.87$?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a number $N$.  Graph the binomial distribution of the number of successes in $N$ trials, where each trial succeeds with probability $c$.  From this distribution, you can calculate $\delta$ such that $99.9\%$ of the graph lies between $c \pm \delta$.

Alternatively, you can pick a value for $\delta$ and determine the value of $N$ that would put $99.9\%$ of the graph between $c \pm \delta$.

Perform the test $N$ times.  If the result is between $c\pm\delta$, then the result is confirmed.  If not, the result is excluded with $99.9\%$ likelihood.

Things get weird if $c$ is close to $0$ or to $1$.  In those cases, you'll prefer an asymmetric range.  My recommendation is to draw a horizontal line that intersects the distribution in two places, and pick those two intersection points as your range.  If it only intersects at one point, then $0$ or $1$ would be the other end of the range.